# How to style certain parts of template literal

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a template literla in my method (vue.js):

```
methodNameDisplay(m) {
  let nameToDisplay = '';
  if (m.friendlyName === m.methodName) {
    nameToDisplay = m.friendlyName;
  } else {
    nameToDisplay = `${m.friendlyName} - ${m.methodName}`;
  }
  return nameToDisplay;
}
```

This method is used to return the value of a title here:

```
<MethodRepeaterTitle :title="showMName ? methodNameDisplay(m) :m.friendlyName" />
```

The issue I am facing is that I need to style the second part of the template literal after the hyphen. How can I go about doing this?

I have tried adding a span to the template literal but this just renders as a string, Vue does not recognize the tag.

Comment: You would need to pass a second property and style it within the component.

Comment: _"but this just renders as a string"_ This to protect users from XSS attacks and preventing arbitrary HTML (incl. JavaScript) from being injected in to the page.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem you can use `v-html`.

I imagine you have something like this inside your component

```
<div>
 {{ title }}
</div>
```

Two handle and render html you need to do this:

```
<div v-html="title" />
```

Like this is say in comment, this can lead to xss attacks. But if you render nothing from the api it's not relevant. In other case you case use a pakage to clean the v-html like [dom-purify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-dompurify-html).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the vue `slot` API. Here is the document.

https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html

With the slot, you can use the vue template in your code

```js
<MethodRepeaterTitle>
  // .... your template
</MethodRepeaterTitle>
```